# Unable to sort the records in Data Flow Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sorting, ssis

I am trying to load around 7 million records from a flat file into a database. I need to sort these records for merging. My sort task within DFT(Data Flow Task) is able to read 7 million rows as input but outputs only 90k rows. Is there anny limit on the number of rows that can be sorted in SSIS? If yes, what are the possible alternatives.

Comment: If you **need** to use the merge in `SSIS`, it would be better to have your set pre-sorted and avoiding the `SORT` operator of `SSIS`. You can sort it in your query and then set the `IsSorted` property of your data source to `true`.

Comment: Does it finish as successful after 90k rows? I don't believe there would be that kind of limit.

Comment: @Rigerta Thanks for the reply. I can't pre-sort the data as it is in csv format. For that i'll have to load it into a stage table and then sort it. This might end up becoming more time consuming.

Comment: @Rich Yeah, it ends up successfully after sorting those 90k rows. Even I tried searching online and haven't come across any kind of limit.

Comment: Do you have 'remove rows with duplicate values' checked? That would filter out rows. If so, get rid of that tick. If not, I'd put data viewers above and below the sort and run in debug to see what rows aren't making it past the Sort.

Comment: @ShashankGupta I would still go for that, at least to try it performance-wise. Some `Sort Considerations` are mentioned [here](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-what-the-sorts-731/).
I think they are relevant especially when having such a big dataset.

Comment: @Rich I figured out the issue. I put the data viewers and it were the null and blank values in certain columns which was making the package fail. Now it works smoothly. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, glad you found it. Would you please pop in an answer to your question so it is no longer marked as unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was blanks and null values existing in certain columns. I added the conditional split transformation and removed the null and blank values. The null and blank values in my file broke the sort transformation resulting in just few rows getting sorted.